# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied in Kentico

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, kentico

I am getting this

> error : 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

While I trying to login to admin panel of kentico 10 using any users in the database.

I was synchronising the pages using staging module, after synchronising this issue appears.

Looks like none have editor access which is the minimum privilege level.

I tried to alter DB but that tool not worked.

How to solve this issues?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server itself, you may need to do an emergency password reset.

In the web.config, under the AppKeys, place this:

Of course replacing "admin" with the username, "password" with the new password, and the "true" is simply stating this user will have global admin privileges.

The key will auto delete after the site recycles, once you have a global admin user you can set user permissions properly.

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/securing-websites/designing-secure-websites/securing-user-accounts-and-passwords/forgotten-password

Comment: This issues not a authentication issue, this is a authorization issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the users on both the system are same then you could modify the users' object from your origin server and make sure they have minimum required access level and then sync these users using staging module.

After that you should be able to access the admin using one of the intended user on the target server.

Comment: i could login in source server, only target have issues. what modification i need to do to users in source server?

Comment: If the users on both server are same, assuming users on the target server were sync from source server, you need to make sure that the user has minimum privileges set on the source server. After that sync up that user object from the source to the target.

Comment: i will make sure, i am unable to login to target

Answer (score 0):

If the source instance was upgraded from version 9 to version 10 while there were some user object synchronization tasks pending, synchronizing them after upgrade very likely caused corruption on your target instance. This scenario is illegal, all synchronization tasks have to be synced to the target before upgrading or discarded as mentioned in documentation:

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-10

I would try to run complete synchronization from the source for all users objects and if this does not fix your target instance you will have to roll it back/install fresh target and make sure you won't sync any old (v9) tasks to the target (v10). Generally staging is supported only between two instances of same major and minor version.

Comment: i am only syching the tasks which is from migrated vesion 10.0 not from old version.

Comment: There should be no "migrated tasks" in the first place - this is unsupported scenario. Tasks are not upgraded with the upgrade procedure. If you upgraded your k9 instance with some tasks pending, they are still v9 tasks and you cannot sync those to k10 instance.